Discriminate between splitscreen and freeform windows
There is an Activity::isInMultiWindowMode or similar method that returns whether an activity is currently in multi-window mode, but is there any analogy to tell whether the multi window implementation it is currently in is splitscreen or freeform?

Related: How to determine correct device orientation in Android N multi-window mode?

Is that related in any capacity other than a tangent? This couldn't be used to actually distinguish between the two modes, could it?

Example 2 in this answer to What's the difference between 'window' and 'screen' in the Dimensions API is what I think I was getting at.

That is noteworthy, but is its behavior any different between splitscreen and freeform? Will a freeform app not also return different sizes for the window and screen, as a splitscreen app does?

Sorry I haven't played around with this in a very long time. I was using: https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/MultiWindowPlayground which sadly hasn't been updated for newer APIs so feel free to self-answer your findings.

Found Jetpack Windows Manager Sample: https://github.com/android/platform-samples/tree/main/samples/user-interface/windowmanager

I'm seeing half-baked documentation at best or this library, but it looks like it is specifically for folding devices
